# How to pass the same data with different value with putExtra()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, service

I am working with a service class that needs to know if the application is running in background or not. To do so, I created a boolean variable called `activityVisible` in my service. I need to update it constantly to know wether the app is in background or active. 
I do this by sending `true` on the `onResume()` method in my activity like this:

`intent.putExtra("Activity Visible", true)`

and `false` on the `onPause()` method like this:

`intent.putExtra("Activity Visible", false)`

However, I print the extra in my service and it is always getting `true`. What I think it is happening is that once you put an extra, you cannot update its value, and that may be the reason it is not working.

Any way I can do the same in a different way? Or a solution to the way I am implementing this?

Comment: could you please add some code? it would be very useful to see how you are firing the intent and how you are reading it

Comment: Why don't you use a foreground service? it will be available even if app is running in background and I believe there is no way to figure out if user just kills the app directly (no callback as such) and if possible please share some more code

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to store the current state of the app.

to reference to the SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to set a boolean in the shared preference, you need to use its editor, so apply this code in onPause, and onResume, while changing the "isVisible" value based on your need

```
boolean isVisible = true;
SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = sp.edit();
editor.putBoolean("activity_visible", isVisible);
editor.apply(); // use apply to confirm the edit
```

and in order to get the value stored, you can simply refer to it using

```
boolean valueStored = sp.getBoolean("activity_visible", false /* Default value if not existed */);
Log.d("Activity State: ", "Boolean: " + valueStored);
```

and do whatever you want with that valueStored.